# Spring boot rest best practices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

this is the first time I am creating restful services using spring Boot.  I am little bit confused about best url practice should I use the following ?

```
  @DeleteMapping ("/cars/delete/{id}")
```

Or

```
@DeleteMapping ("/cars/{id}")
```

Because I will already be having a get mapping for ("/cars/{id}") but annotation is different as I will be using this

```
@GetMapping ("/cars/{id}")
```

While for delete or put mapping I will be using their respective annotations

So can I use same path with different mapping or I should use different paths too with different mappings ?

Comment: It is better to use different mapping for each operation. because by mistake if someone uses DELETE instead of GET, it will be a problem. If there is a different mapping it will throw method not allowed exception

Comment: `@DeleteMapping ("/car/{id}")` because with the Rest operator you are "managing" the suitable one, I mean, it is not required to include the "double delete mention" with the path

Comment: Thank you both for comments, I think I'll go with @pradyskumar's answer, as it has a valid logic.

Comment: @Pradyskumar Why should the API developer care about the user misusing the API? User can mess-up the URL as well as the HTTP method. Only way to avoid that would be to disallow removal altogether.

Comment: @jannis weather or not API developer care about user misusing the API is clearly personal choice. But I believe taking extra care is always better. I am a fullstack developer. Maybe my thought process is a result of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restful convention says you should design your urls to be resource related and use HTTP methods as the verbs. The best practice in this case would be to use

```
@DeleteMapping("/cars/{id}")
```

You should not worry about your consumers accidentally calling the wrong method. This is well known to be the best practice as restful urls do not contain verbs like delete.

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately my reputation is not enough to upvote

Comment: You should be able to accept that as an answer. You don't high rep to mark which is the accepted answer. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thankyou, I did it , actually I didn't know how to pick an answer here